# PHP variable seems always set

Tags: php, isset

I am trying a quick and simple page with a form

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<select name="nome">
<option selected="selected" value="Cactus">Cactus</option>
<option value="Sequoia">Sequoia</option>
<option value="Baobab">Baobab</option>
</select>
Quantità 
<input type="text" name="numero" size="2" style="text-align:right">
<input type="submit" value="Invia">
</form>

<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST['nome'])){
   $pianta = "Cactus";
   $num = 0;
}
   $pianta = $_REQUEST['nome'];
   $num = $_REQUEST['numero'];
?>
```

My problem is that issset($_REQUEST['nome']) seems to be always true, even if I reload the page. I mean, my browser seems to remember my previous choice.

If I reload the page, $_REQUEST['nome']) is always set, even it I didn't choose anything. I tried this in a local server (USBWebServer) and with different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE), always with the same result: reloading the page does not delete variables content.

Where is my error? Thanks a lot

Giancarlo - Italy

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `isset()`

Comment: Aside from your problem, this code makes no much sense.

Comment: the browser remembering your setting "even on reload" is actually a feature from most browsers. however, going into the address bar and pressing enter usually "resets" the form. also, your form always seems to pre-select cactus.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an if-else-statement. Change your PHP-code like this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST['nome'])){
   $pianta = "Cactus";
   $num = 0;
} else {
   $pianta = $_REQUEST['nome'];
   $num = $_REQUEST['numero'];
}
?>
```

I hope this helps. Otherwise you need to provide us some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Smart thing would be, to do as below, you don't even need `else`:

```
<?php
$pianta = "Cactus";
$num = 0;
if (isset($_REQUEST['nome'])){
    $pianta = $_REQUEST['nome'];
    $num = $_REQUEST['numero'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions. But the problem is that my browser seems to remember my previous choice. If I reload the page, $_REQUEST['nome']) is always set, even it I didn't choose anything. I tried this in a local server (USBWebServer) and with different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE), always this the same result: reloading the page does not delete variables content.